# build deb package that uninstall another package in case of remove or purge

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, package-management, dpkg, packaging

i try to build an package, which can uninstall another package, if my package should be uninstall.

I have tryed the "Depends" and the "Pre-Depends" policy in the control file. But its not neccessary, that the second package is installed before my package can be installed. Thats the reason, why i dont want this policies.

Further that i have tried to uninstall the other package in the 'postrm' file. But this dont work too, because the lockfile on dpkg is set from the uninstaller from my package.

Summarized:
how its possible to purge another package, as soon as my package is removed or purged?

Theoretically, it would be enough for me to delete the other package in the postrm file.

Or if I can mark the other package as no longer needed, but it would be nicest if dpkg uninstalls both packages when my package is deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How its possible to purge another package, as soon as my package is removed or purged.

It does not work that way. Suppose, your package (`A`), depends on another package (`B`), which would be automatically be installed from the repositories when you manually install `A`.

When you remove `A`, dpkg/apt will not automatically remove `B`.

You will have to manually run `sudo apt autoremove` to remove `B` and other packages which were installed as dependencies, and are no longer required.

If you want to do both in one go, you can run the command

```
sudo apt remove A && sudo apt autoremove
```

where `A` is the name of the main package.

Comment: ok, thank you. Thats not the solition i want, but if there no other way, than i have to accept it. :D

Comment: What if the user decides he wants B installed, before or after he installs your A? What if a package C depends on B? What if C gets installed before or after your A install? There's just too many ways to break things if you automatically uninstall B, which is why apt works the way it does.

Comment: @Guntram Blohm
you are right, i dont think so far